# My buttons are in a class, how do I use if statement based on id?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a set of buttons in a class, and I'm trying to run a function so a piece of HTML will change based on what button was pressed. How would I use if/else statement to change the outcome based on the id of the button?

```
document.querySelector(".pizza").addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (document.getElementById("small").clicked == true) {
    Size_Price = 5;
    document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Small";
  } else if (document.getElementById("medium").clicked == true) {
    Size_Price = 10;
    document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Medium";
  }
})
```

This is what I've tried, to no avail.

Comment: The callback function passed to `addEventListener` receives an argument for the click event.  That argument contains a `target` which was the clicked element, including any properties/data on that element.